# How to do type-safe web service calls in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, web-services, typescript

When making a web service call with Angular the type of the returned object isn't verified. This can mean that I have a Typescript class:

```
export class Course {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public description: string,
    public startDate: Date
  ) {}
}
```

and a DataService class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: 
true });
    return this.http.get(url, options)
      .map(response => response.json() as T);
  }
}
```

and then do:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Course } from './course';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
})
export class CourseComponent {
  private courseId: number;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  public getData() {
    this.dataService.get<Course>(`http://myapi/course/${this.courseId}`)
    .subscribe(
      course => this.course = course;
    );
  }
}
```

and I will get no compile errors as my data service correctly returns me an object of type "Course".

If however my API actually returned me the following JSON:

```
{
    "uniqueId": 123,
    "name": "CS 101",
    "summary": "An introduction to Computer Science",
    "beginDate": "2018-04-20"
}
```

I would get no compile time error, and would only get a runtime error if I try and do some operations on the non-existing properties (id, summary, startDate). This removes some of the type safety from TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

We can fix this by modifying our data service as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  private verifyObjectWithTemplate(template: any,  obj: any, graph: string[]) {
    if (!template) {
      return;
    }

    const graphString = graph.join('.');

    Object
      .getOwnPropertyNames(template)
      .forEach(property => {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          console.error(`Object is missing property: ${graphString}.${property}`);
        } else {
          const newGraph = graph.map(i => i);
          newGraph.push(property);
          this.verifyObjectWithTemplate(template[property], obj[property], newGraph);
        }
      });
  }

  public get<T>(url: string, template: T): Observable<T> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
    return this.http.get(url, options)
      .map(response => {
        const obj = response.json() as T;
        this.verifyObjectWithTemplate(template, obj, []);
        return obj;
      });
  }
}
```

add a "template" to our Course class:

```
export class Course {
  public static readonly Template = new Course(-1, '', '', new Date());
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public description: string,
    public startDate: Date
  ) {}
}
```

and modify our Course component to pass the template to the data service:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Course } from './course';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
})
export class CourseComponent {
  private courseId: number;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  public getData() {
    this.dataService.get<Course>(`http://myapi/course/${this.courseId}`, Course.Template)
    .subscribe(
      course => this.course = course;
    );
  }
}
```

The data service will then verify that the JSON returned by the API has all the required properties to be a valid Course object.

What about arrays?
What about if one of our classes contains an array, for example our Student class:

```
import { Course } from './course';

export class Student {
  public static readonly Template = new Student(-1, '', [Course.Template]);
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public courses: Course[]
  ) {}
}
```

In this case, we need to ensure that any arrays in the template contain one item, so this can be verified too. We also need to update our data service as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  private verifyObjectWithTemplate(template: any,  obj: any, graph: string[]) {
    if (!template) {
      return;
    }

    const graphString = graph.join('.');

    // Important that we compare object to undefined, and not to null.
    // Property being null can be valid.
    if (obj === undefined) {
      console.error(`Object is missing property: ${graphString}`);
      return;
    }

    if (obj === null) {
        // No need to check rest of graph if object is null.
        return;
    }

    if (Array.isArray(template)) {
      if (!template[0]) {
        console.error(`Template array is empty: ${graphString}`);
        return;
      }

      if (!Array.isArray(obj)) {
        console.error(`Object is not an array: ${graphString}`);
        return;
      }

      if (!obj[0]) {
        console.log(`Object array is empty so can't be verified: ${graphString}`);
        return;
      }

      template = template[0];
      obj = obj[0];
    }

    Object
      .getOwnPropertyNames(template)
      .forEach(property => {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          console.error(`Object is missing property: ${graphString}.${property}`);
        } else {
          const newGraph = graph.map(i => i);
          newGraph.push(property);
          this.verifyObjectWithTemplate(template[property], obj[property], newGraph);
        }
      });
  }

  public get<T>(url: string, template: T): Observable<T> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: 
true });
    return this.http.get(url, options)
      .map(response => {
        const obj = response.json() as T;
        this.verifyObjectWithTemplate(template, obj, []);
        return obj;
      });
  }
}
```

This should now be able to handle all type of objects.

Example
If the web service returned the JSON:

```
{
    "uniqueId": 1,
    "name": "Daniel",
    "courses": [
        {
            "uniqueId": 123,
            "name": "CS 101",
            "summary": "An introduction to Computer Science",
            "beginDate": "2018-04-20"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then we would see the following messages in the console:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmDBy.jpg)